# Cloning only the value of a variable

Tags: php

Im trying to make some kind of ambience randomizer, which picks a random ambience at every page load, but I also want it to avoid picking the same one from the previous page.

```
$amblst = array(1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10);

if (($key = array_search($_SESSION['ambprev'], $amblst)) !== false) {
    unset($array[$key]);
}

$ambnum = $ambnum + 1;
$ambnum = array_rand($amblst);

$_SESSION['ambprev'] = clone $ambnum;
```

However using clone breaks the page for some reason and I don't have access to the error logs, so I can't provide that right now.

I just want to clone the variable's value, nothing more.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`clone` keyword is used to create an **object** copy, not variable.

> An object copy is created by using the **clone** keyword (which calls
>   the object's `__clone()` method if possible)

http://php.net/manual/en/language.oop5.cloning.php

---

In your case it's enough to assign a copy of the `$ambnum` variable value:

```
$_SESSION['ambprev'] = $ambnum;
```